# Scrolling Text not working

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, textview

I have the following textView in my activity's layout and i want it to scroll horizontal automatically but that doesn't happen. Does anyone here know why this happens?

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/superAttackDesc"
    android:layout_width="314dp"
    android:layout_height="21dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:fontFamily="monospace"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/cardDetailsImageView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.753"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/superAttackTitle"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.175" />
```

Comment: what do you mean by **scroll horizontal automatically?**

Comment: @AmitVaghela most likely scroll when the text is too wide instead of adding new lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) To make textview horizontal scroll set **[android:singleLine](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:singleLine) = true** and **[android:ellipsize](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:ellipsize)="marquee"**

2) Make sure that TextView is selected in onCreate of Parent Activity.

```
findViewById(R.id.SAMPLE).setSelected(true);
```

Code reference:

```
<TextView
 android:id="@+id/SAMPLE"
 android:layout_width="..."
 android:layout_height="..."
 android:ellipsize="marquee"
 android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
 android:singleLine="true"
 android:text="@string/SAMPLE"/>
```